Warehouse aisles and ramp requirements for pallet hand trucks
Are there any regulations for warehouses that define maximum slope and minimum aisle lengths for moving pallets with hydraulic, manual pallet jacks?
Given a ramp that was designed for wheelchairs, I'm wondering if it's possible to also pull pallets of goods along that slope. I have two concerns:

Is the slope too great to be dangerous?
Are the corners of the ramp too tight for a pallet truck pulling a standard pallet to maneuver?

Consider, for example, the following ramp. The ramp is 1 meter wide and has a slope of 8.276% (rise 2.4 meters over run 29 meters = 2.4/29 = 0.082758621).








This ramp was designed for wheelchairs. Is it safe and possible to use for moving pallets with a pallet truck?



And consider the use of EUR-pallet @ 1200 mm x 800 mm.








Typical loaded pallet on a manual pallet jack



How can I determine if [a] the slope is safe for my pallet loads and [b] what are the minimum required space around a curve to be able to maneuver a pallet around a hairpin turn in a ramp?

See also https://www.osha.gov/etools/woodworking/packaging-shipping/forklifts-pallet-jacks


the weight capacity.  Generally a pallet jack is needed for heavy things... A person in a wheelchair is usually light by comparison.


stability of load? speed? total mass?

From wikipedia "The safe working load of a EUR/EPAL-pallet is 1,500 kg". But, rather than answer my specific example, a better answer would provide a formula for the reader to determine the requirements for various pallet dimensions and loads. There are no speed requirements. This question is to figure out how to determine if a pallet jack physically has enough space to maneuver around a tight corner (at near-zero speed) or not. And if there are any regulatory requirements that define these minimum dimensions, for safety.

See also OSHA 1926.451(e)(5)(ii), which says "No ramp or walkway shall be inclined more than a slope of one (1) vertical to three (3) horizontal". That's 1/3 = 0.3333 slope = 33.33% grade

@MichaelAltfield why are you commenting on your own question? ... all info belongs in the question ... this site is not a forum, the comments are not part of the question ... please edit your question and delete the comments

See also https://industrialtoolz.com/material-handling-ramp/

See also Mountain Roads’ Geometric Design: Methodological Proposal for Hairpin Bend Design/Retrofitting

Two important metrics that industrial engineers use for designing warehouses aisle dimensions for forklifts and pallet jacks are the device's Turning Radius and Basic Right-Angle Stack. The question you're asking is specifically trying to determine the "Wall-To-Wall" Turning Circle, which is defined on wikipedia as "how far apart the two walls would have to be to allow a U-turn without scraping the walls. "

"The space required to turn a manual pallet truck with a fork length of 1150 mm is 2540 mm." Source: https://www.forkliftaction.com/news/newsdisplay.aspx?nwid=9135

@MichaelAltfield please stop writing information in comments... this site is NOT a forum ... use the edit button and update your question instead

@jsotola please stop posting unhelpful comments on this question. This site is NOT a forum. Please delete your comments; let's keep things on-topic.

3-5% is the maximum.
I have seen this a few times, this resource gives it as the limit:
https://warehousewiz.com/blogs/news/can-a-pallet-jack-go-up-a-ramp#:~:text=As%20a%20general%20guideline%2C%20many,inclines%20compared%20to%20manual%20ones.

A load (W) on an incline (with angle $\phi$) has two force components - sliding force (Wsin$\phi$) and normal force (Wcos$\phi$). The push or the pull force required to roll the load is the sum of the sliding force and the friction force generated by the normal force - $F_p$ = Wsin$\phi$ +  $\mu$Wcos$\phi$, where $\mu$ is the friction coefficient of the wheel on-ramp.
Assume that a 200lb healthy worker may pull or push a load of half his weight, the minimum force required to move the load is then $F_p$ = Wsin$\phi$ +  $\mu$Wcos$\phi$ = 100. Now, if the anticipated weight of the load and the friction coefficient are known, you can solve the slope's maximum angle ($phi) from the equation above.
To be safe, reduce the angle by half :)

Ramp Slope
If you're planning on using a ramp that was designed for wheelchair users, then it's probably safe to use for moving pallets.
According to OSHA 1926.451(e)(5)(ii):

No ramp or walkway shall be inclined more than a slope of one (1) vertical to three (3) horizontal". That's 1/3 = 0.3333 slope = 33.33% grade

The EU doesn't appear to have any publicly-accessible standards for maximum slope of ramps, but the US ADA has a maximum slope of 1/12 = 0.0833 = 8.33% grade, but 1/20 = 0.05 = 5% grade is also quite common.
Some warehouses advocate for a maximum ramp slope of 10% grade.

Our safety recommendation sets the maximum material handling ramp slope of 5.7% degrees (10% grade) which calculates to a ratio of 10’ of ramp for every 1’ of rise

In any case, the requirements for wheelchair ramps are almost always less-steep than warehouse ramps, so you shouldn't have issues moving loaded pallet jacks on ramps that are spec'd to be sloped for wheelchairs.
Ramp Width
To determine the minimum width of the ramp required for a pallet jack, what you need to determine is the Wall-to-Wall Turning Circle.








Wendekresis = Wall-to-Wall Turning Radius defines the radius needed for a vehicle to make a complete U-turn without scraping the walls with that radius. This is the absolute minimum space needed for the turnaround of your ramp.



This is something you should get from the manufacturer specifications of your pallet jack. It should be called the outer turning radius.
A quick google for some manufacturers of pallet jacks with fork lengths = 1200 mm (the length of EUR-pallets) shows a slightly higher turning radius than the length of the pallet, ranging from 1265 to 1400 mm.
Therefore, 1-meter-wide ramps probably won't work for pallet jacks carrying EUR-pallets. You'll either need to disassemble the pallets, use smaller pallets, widen the ramp, or make much bigger landing areas to accommodate a wider turning radius.
